# Detach and append element until there is no overflow - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

I am trying to `detach()` an element from its parent (zone-col) and append to the next `.zone-col` until its new parent no longer overflows the zone.

So, in my example, the widget should be appended to the first `.zone-col` of the second row, and the loop should break out because its new parent shouldn't be overflowing the zone.

Not sure I quite understand do while loops as I've created an infinite loop...

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/KKKWwed)

```js
$(function() {

  var zone = $('.zone');
  var el = $('.active');

  var zW = zone.outerWidth();
  var zR = zone.offset().left + zW;

  var eW = el.outerWidth();
  var eR = el.offset().left + eW;

  console.log(eR, zR);

  while (eR > zR) {
    var de = el.find('.widget').detach();
    el = el.nextAll('.zone-col:first');

    el.append(de);

    if (!eR > zR) {
      break;
    }
  }


});
```

```css
.zone {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.zone-col {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 8.333333%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.widget {
  width: 496px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zone">
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 0; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 8.333333%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col active" style="left: 16.666667%; top: 0;">
    <div class="widget"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 25%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 33.333333%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 41.666667%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 50%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 58.333333%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 66.666667%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 75%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 83.333333%; top: 0;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 91.666667%; top: 0;"></div>

  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 0; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 8.333333%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 16.666667%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 25%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 33.333333%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 41.666667%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 50%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 58.333333%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 66.666667%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 75%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 83.333333%; top: 100px;"></div>
  <div class="zone-col" style="left: 91.666667%; top: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to reset `eW` and `eR` each time the loop runs, otherwise the loop is always getting the first initialized value of those variables.

```
while (eR > zR) {
  var de = el.find('.widget').detach();
  el = el.nextAll('.zone-col:first');
  el.append(de);

  eW = el.outerWidth();
  eR = el.offset().left + eW;   

  if (!eR > zR) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the comparison values inside of your loop. Right now eR is always greater than zR, causing the infinte loop.